# SQL Server Collation conflict - creating a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to create a View in a Database A, that is filled by a select from the Database B and i am having a collation conflict, to be more exactly , its between ( Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_BIN ). WHere(in the code) i need to put the collate?

Best Regards.

The code is here:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CML_SDG_MENSAL_ESTOQUE]
AS

select  
SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.val_fatur) val_fatur, 
SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.val_receita) val_receita, 
SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.qtd_bonif_item) qtd_bonif_item, 
SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.val_bonif_fatur) val_bonif_fatur,
SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.val_bonif_receita) val_bonif_receita,
SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.val_devol_fatur) val_devol_fatur,
SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.val_devol_receita) val_devol_receita,
DW_DIM_PRODUTO.B1_CODDB B1_CODDB,
dw_fato_faturmes.cod_produto cod_produto, 
SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.qtd_estoque) qtd_estoque, 
SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.qtd_devol) qtd_devol, 
SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.qtd_item) qtd_item, 
SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.qtd_meta) qtd_meta,
SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.qtd_pedido) qtd_pedido,
SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.qtd_item)+
    SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.qtd_bonif_item)+
    SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.qtd_devol) venda_liquida
(SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.qtd_item)
     +SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.qtd_bonif_item)
    +SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.qtd_devol))
    +SUM(dw_fato_faturmes.qtd_pedido) venda___pedido
FROM 
logixbi.dbo.dw_fato_faturmes dw_fato_faturmes, 
logixbi.dbo.DW_DIM_CLIENTE DW_DIM_CLIENTE, 
DW_DIM_EMPRESA DW_DIM_EMPRESA, 
logixbi.dbo.DW_DIM_MARCA DW_DIM_MARCA, 
logixbi.dbo.DW_DIM_PRODUTO DW_DIM_PRODUTO, 
logixbi.dbo.DW_DIM_REPRESENTANTE DW_DIM_REPRESENTANTE

where 
DW_DIM_EMPRESA.SM0_FILIAL=dw_fato_faturmes.filial and
DW_DIM_MARCA.BM_GRUPO=dw_fato_faturmes.grupo and
DW_DIM_PRODUTO.B1_COD=dw_fato_faturmes.cod_produto and
DW_DIM_REPRESENTANTE.A3_COD=dw_fato_faturmes.vendedor and
DW_DIM_CLIENTE.A1_COD=dw_fato_faturmes.cliente and
DW_DIM_CLIENTE.A1_LOJA=dw_fato_faturmes.loja

group by DW_DIM_PRODUTO.B1_CODDB,dw_fato_faturmes.cod_produto
```

Comment: In case some of the answers was usefull (one was indeed according to your comment) click on `ACCEPT´ to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Once you reach [15 reputation you can upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where to put it depends on where the conflict is.

I'd suggest on the joins

ie

```
DW_DIM_EMPRESA.SM0_FILIAL COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS =dw_fato_faturmes.filial COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to find wich column has wich collation use this snippet:

```
SELECT name, collation_name
  FROM sys.columns
  WHERE OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID
                        FROM sys.objects
                       WHERE type = 'U'
                         AND name = 'your_table_name'
                      )
    AND name = 'your_column_name'
```

Once you find the columns try this:

```
column_1 COLLATE your_collation = column_2 COLLATE your_collation
```

It is better to stick to a single collation globally. Otherwise you will have problems. Here is a snippet that will give you all the columns on your database with a `COLLATION` different than the one in the database

```
SELECT [TABLE_NAME] = OBJECT_NAME([id]),
       [COLUMN_NAME] = [name],
       [COLLATION_NAME] = collation
  FROM syscolumns
 WHERE collation <> 'your_database_collation_type'
   AND collation IS NOT NULL
   AND OBJECTPROPERTY([id], N'IsUserTable')=1
```

Comment: Yaroslav, i will try your solution later, when i got some time, by the way, thank you so much for answering!

Comment: You are welcome. My solution is exactly the same as the other ones, is 2nd code snippet on my answer. I just added more details to check for `COLLATION` issues as it can be a problem if you don't take care of it on early stages.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to operation between different collation types so try this for statement for comparison.

```
ColumnA = ColumnB collate database_default
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in all your character matching conditions in where clause:

```
colnameA COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = columnnameB COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```